# Recursive function does not display anything

Tags: php, mysql, jstree

I have a tree with nodes and I wanted to display every node's level in a table, 
but when it does not display anything.

I tried to put a comment when I do: findlevel($_SESSION['id'], $level +1, $idtofind); at the end of the function, if I do that it works but only for the first level of the Tree.

My code:

```
function findlevel($parent_id, $level, $idtofind)
                    {
                    global $data, $index, $tree;
                    $parent_id = $parent_id === NULL ? "NULL" : $parent_id;

                        if (isset($index[$parent_id])) {
                            foreach ($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
                                $current_id      = $data[$id]["id"];
                                $levell = $level+1;
                                if($current_id == $idtofind) {
                                    echo $current_id . " " . $idtofind . $levell . "<br>";
                                    return $levell;                     
                                }
                                findlevel($_SESSION['id'], $level + 1, $idtofind);
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Code of my table:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, email, tipoutente, fullname, datainserimento, DATEDIFF(datainserimento, '$datainserimentosponsor') AS datadiff FROM utenti WHERE inseritoda = " . $_SESSION['id']);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr class=\"righe\">";

    $levelnode =findlevel($_SESSION['id'], 0, $row['id']);

    if($row['tipoutente'] == "GRUPPO PRIVATO" || $row['tipoutente'] == "GRUPPO NEGOZI" || $row['tipoutente'] == "GRUPPO ASSOCIAZIONI") {

            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">$progressivoutenti</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['fullname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['tipoutente'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['datainserimento'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['datadiff'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $levelnode . "</td>";
        //} 
            } else {

            echo "<td class=\"dati\">$progressivoutenti</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['fullname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['tipoutente'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['datainserimento'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['datadiff'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $levelnode . "</td>";
            }
            $progressivoutenti++;
    echo "</tr>";   
}
echo "</table>";
```

Edit:

This is the rest of the code:

```
 $data = array();
$index = array();
$albero = array();
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM utenti where utentepadre is not null order by fullname");
$query->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id        = $row["id"];
    $parent_id = $row["utentepadre"] === NULL ? "NULL" : $row["utentepadre"];
    $data[$id] = $row;
    $index[$parent_id][] = $id;
}
```

That's how my tree looks like:

[My Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7TJy.jpg)

And the result is:

[The result of the php page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWgb9.jpg)

The result of the variable $data:

[Variable $data content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKnqA.jpg)

Comment: It would help if we knew what $data and $index looked like in the case where it doesn't work, and also exactly what result you're expecting instead. P.S. $tree is imported as a global into findLevel, but then seems not to be used at all in that function, is that the intention?

Comment: I edited my question with the first code in my page.

Comment: that's a useful start, thanks, but actually I meant a var_dump output of the state of those variables at the time the findlevel method is first called, so we can easily see the structure of the arrays. We don't know how many rows, or exactly what the contents of the data was. Having some sample data, and some sample expected output from the findLevel function, would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: I added the images for better explanations.

Comment: Ok thanks. But also, like I said before what were you _expecting_ the output to look like? Is it supposed to look like the tree? How is the tree related? It isn't used in the findLevel function. The output of your page looks like it's just the output of the table...so I guess findLevel didn't echo anything at all, is that right? Sorry but it still isn't totally clear what you actually want.